# How to await nongeneric Task using Async workflow?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, f#-3.0

How do you await nongeneric Tasks in F# `async` workflows?

```
open System.IO

let openConnection = async { ... }

let answer = async {
    use! stream = openConnection
    let reader = new StreamReader (stream)
    let! request = reader.ReadLineAsync () |> Async.AwaitTask // works fine: Task<String>
    ...
    let writer = new StreamWriter (stream)
    do! writer.WriteLineAsync "OK" |> Async.AwaitTask // error: Task
}
```

Visual Studio complains that the type `Task` is not compatible with type `Task<'a>`. Is there a way to transform the `Task` to `Task<Unit>`?

Using Visual Studio 2012 & F# 3.0...

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was looking for. The search for "nongeneric" yielded no results for me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, maybe you can use (writer.WriteLineAsync "OK").Wait() or do! async {writer.WriteLine "OK"}, for asynchronous use (writer.WriteLineAsync "OK").Start() or async {writer.WriteLine "OK"} |> Async.Start

Comment: The linked question provided exactly the answers I was looking for. The code you suggested wouldn't work for me because the workflow should only continue after the `WriteLineAsync` call has finished, and not simply start a new Task and go on.